# List comparison with double check on voucher no. and amount

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have 2 lists with this structure:

```
public class DepositAssembly
{
    public string VoucherNo { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
}

public class MpesaAssembly
{
    public string ReceiptNo { get; set; }
    public double PaidIn { get; set; }
}
```

The deposit assembly is entered into an ERP system. The Mpesa is produced from a .csv file to ensure that payments have been made.

I want to compare the 2 lists to make sure that:
1. All vouchers/ReceiptNos in DepositAssembly are found in the MpesaAssembly. If not, show an error.
2. That the vouchers that match have the same exact amount, if amounts are different, show error.

```
E.g. DepositAssembly   VoucherNo         Total
                       icdiihiasi        GBP 5,319.39
                       uhuixjisdjodvo    GBP 4,790.73       
     MpesaAssembly     ReceiptNo         PaidIn           
                       icdiihiasi        5,319.39
                       uhuixjisdjodvo    4,790.73
```

Above should go through

```
 DepositAssembly   VoucherNo         Total
                   icdiihiasii       GBP 5,319.39
                   uhuixjisdjodvo    GBP 4,790.73       
 MpesaAssembly     ReceiptNo         PaidIn                             
                   icdiihiasi        5,319.39
                   uhuixjisdjodvo    4,790.73
```

Above should fail on 1st voucher number as it cannot be found in Mpesa .csv

```
 DepositAssembly   VoucherNo         Total
                   icdiihiasi       GBP 5,319.39
                   uhuixjisdjodvo    GBP 4,790.73       
 MpesaAssembly     ReceiptNo         PaidIn                             
                   icdiihiasi        5,319.39
                   uhuixjisdjodvo    4,800.73
```

Above should fail on uhuixjisdjodvo receipt number PaidIn as it is not the same as that in the DepositAssembly.

Any linq function to do this?

I have

```
   var requestWithMatches = from req in depositAssembly
                                             join resp in mpesaAssembly
                                             on req.VoucherNo equals resp.ReceiptNo  
                                             select new CallPair(req, resp);
```

But this does not take care of amounts. Need to match both vouchers and amounts.

How do I check that the voucher number and totals exists exactly the same as in the Mpesa assemble? Linq example?

Comment: Are you performing LINQ to sql or LINQ to objects? Are you able to configure how how your ERP system entries are mapped into your `DepositAssembly` instances?

Comment: I am able to configure how my ERP system entries are mapped into my DepositAssembly  instances. LINQ to objects.

Comment: Look at MSDN sample for Left Outer Join.  You join is only looking for A->B and not reporting when B is null.  See : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the existence of the following collections:

- `Deposits`: The deposits collection
- `Receipts`: The entries from your .csv file
- `DepositsxReceipts`: The result of joining `Deposits` and `Receipts` on `Deposit.VoucherNo` and `Receipt.ReceiptNo`, and selecting the joined pairs `(deposit, receipt)`

Ill describe how can you archive your goals:

> 1. All vouchers/ReceiptNos in DepositAssembly are found in the MpesaAssembly. If not, show an error.

Check that `DepositsxReceipts.Length` is equal to `Deposits.Length`.
Really straight-forward, there is not much going on here. Depending on how much information you want to have abouth the non-matching pairs, you will need to use a form of outer-join.

> 2. That the vouchers that match have the same exact amount, if amounts are different, show error.

Check that for every pair `(deposit, receipt)` in `DepositsxReceipts` the condition `deposit.Amount == receipt.Total` is true.

Your 2nd goal leaves open room for a couple of ideas

Considering simple *LINQ to objects*, you could do the following:

```
var depositsxReceipts = from deposit in deposits
                         join receipt in receipts
                         on deposit.VoucherNo equals receipt.ReceiptNo
                         select new CallPair(deposit, receipt);
```

In this case, your `CallPair` class could calculate and expose the amount equality condition as follows:

```
Convert.ToDouble(deposit.Total.Split(" ").Last()) == receipt.PaidIn;
```

A much cleaner approach would be to change the class used to map your ERP entries into:

```
public class DepositAssembly
{
    public string VoucherNo { get; set; }
    // In DDD the following props would be encapsulated into a "Money" value-object
    public string Currency {get;set;} // The type of currency, eg.: GBP
    public double Total { get; set; } // The amount of the deposit
}
```

An then the calculation of the amount equality is easier:

```
deposit.Amount == receipt.PaidIn;
```

As this is fairly trivial, you could choose between adding this in your `CallPair` class or calculating it when iterating the joined values (which you have to do in order to validate your 2nd goal).

Comment: I had stripped the currency off the deposit assembly list before the comparison. Works with just iterating deposit.Amount == receipt.PaidIn;

Answer (score 1):

Basically just a loop inside a loop but using an "All" linq query that compares every DepositAssembly to every MpesaAssembly.

```
var result1 = DepositAssemblies.All(Deposit => MpesaAssemblies.Any(mpesa => mpesa.PaidIn.ToString() == Deposit.Total.ToString() &&
                                                                      mpesa.ReceiptNo.ToString() == Deposit.VoucherNo.ToString()));
```

Think the Correct way to do it though is to create anonymous types

```
var MatchesSolution1 = from Deposits in DepositAssemblies
                       join Mpesas in MpesaAssemblies on new { Amount = Mpesas.PaidIn.ToString(), No = Mpesas.ReceiptNo.ToString() } 
                                                  equals new { Amount = Deposits.Total.ToString(), No = Deposits.VoucherNo.ToString() }
```

Another solution is using intersect (which should run the fastest)

```
var MatchesSolution2= DepositAssemblies.Select(Deposit => new { Amount = Deposit.Total.ToString(), No = Deposit.VoucherNo.ToString() })
                               .Intersect(MpesaAssemblies.Select(Mpesa => new { Amount = Mpesa.PaidIn.ToString(), No = Mpesa.ReceiptNo.ToString() }))
                               .ToList();
```

Hope it helps.